# I wrote this code in functions.php in my theme in wp-content in wordpress to call bootstrap.css and font.css ...ect , but it dose not work

Tags: php, wordpress

upload style files and libraries and scripts in function.php  and the I add hook actions:

```
<?php

function khalaf_styles(){
   wp_enqueue_style( 'my-bootstrap.css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css;' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'my-fontawsome.css', get_template_directory_uri().'/fonts/fontawesome.min.css' );
}

function khalaf_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-bootstrap.js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js',array(),false,true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-main.js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/main.js',array(),false,true );
 }
 
 add_action( ' wp_enqueue_scripts','khalaf_styles' );
 add_action( ' wp_enqueue_scripts','khalaf_scripts' );
```

Comment: You don't even need to call the same hook twice, instead of that you can put your style and Js in same function, and just do add action only once.

Answer (score 0):

ops! I detected my wrong ; I did not put `<?php wp_footer ?>` in footer.php before closing tag of the body `</body>` , now the code is running